# laravel public variable becomes null within model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to set webhook url for each event I define.

So I have something like below.

*UserModel*

```
<?php

namespace app\Model\User;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Model\Device as DeviceModel;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package app\Model\User
 */
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $slackChannel;

/**
 * Route notifications for the Nexmo channel.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function routeNotificationForSlack() : string
{
    if ( $this->slackChannel ){
        return config('slack.channels.'.$this->slackChannel);
    }
}

/**
 * @param string $slackChannel
 * @return object
 */
public function slackChannel(string $slackChannel) : object
{
    $this->slackChannel = $slackChannel;
    return $this;
}
```

}

*Job*

```
public function handle()
{
    foreach( $this->users as $user ) {
        $recipient = $user;
        $user->slackChannel('order-requested')->notify(new OrderSubmittedByClient($this->order, $recipient));
    }
  }
```

*config/slack*

```
return [
'channels' => [
    'order-requested' => 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx',
]
];
```

Even after I set `$this->slackChannel` to certain string, when it comes to `routeNotificationForSlack`, it returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect `jwt` in the middleware, but will that matter?

Comment: Share all code from `UserModel` ?

Comment: @C2486 shared all code.

Comment: Is the notification queued?

Comment: Are you using the `SerializesModels` trait in the queued notification?

Comment: Yes. it was. You saved my day. It was silly mistake

Comment: But is there any way I can use this with `queue`?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#queueing-notifications

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I meant if I use `queue` on notification, the way I change slack webhook does not work because it would return null. How would I use both `queue` and dynamic webhook?

Comment: Is direct name works ? `return config('slack.channels.order-requested');`?

Comment: @C2486 Yes. it does.

Comment: @smchae As long as the queue job uses `SerializesModels` any property on the model should be available when the job actually processes.